# Equivalent for System.Diagnostics.Trace in PCL library

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I was surprised to learn that System.Diagnostics.Trace is not included in the Portable Class Library profiles. System.Diagnostics.Debug is available though.

I'm porting a library to a PCL and have typically used Trace statements to provide additional troubleshooting to consumers. For performance reasons, I want the assembly optimized so I only ship Release versions of the assembly in my NuGet package.

My understanding is that the methods for System.Diagnostics.Debug are conditionally compiled and therefore only useful when the assembly includes the DEBUG directive.

If I change my code to use System.Diagnostics.Debug and then compile in Release the approach is useless -- is there an alternative to System.Diagnostics.Trace in PCL or do I have to include the DEBUG directive in my Release build? Or is there another approach I should be considering?

Comment: Trace critically depends on config, which isn't the same across different targets.  Just go shopping for a logging library that's compatible with PCL.  MetroLog for example.

Comment: Understood, though I'm using Trace to support conditions where logging isn't yet available. I have an abstraction for logging, but if that's not working I want to provide a means to dig deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify conditional compilation directives in an individual C# file.  So you can create your own wrapper around Debug.Trace, and define the DEBUG directive just for that code file, which will let you call Debug.Trace from a release DLL.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm sure others will find helpful.

Answer (score 5):

There is a nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.Tracing/4.0.21-beta-23516

This is Microsoft's new PCL for tracing.

Seems to be in beta so far...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11716976)

Comment: That is a complete answer. What more do you want? If a developer can't do a nuget search in the future; then no one can help him...

Comment: So *how does this package solve the problem*. This isn't your package, I presume, but many of the points Brad makes about posting open source packages apply here too: [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085). If the link went away, why should anyone bother tracking it down again?

Comment: Quoting the post: *make sure you write a detailed answer that addresses the specific question asked* and *A simple, blind link to your project isn't acceptable as an answer. Explain what your library is and why it would be a particularly good solution for the problem at hand. Provide sample code of it solving that problem, if applicable.*

Comment: It's not my library, it's Microsoft's!

Comment: This is ridiculous; I'm trying to help people & all you guys are stopping me. This is how I solved the problem for myself! I wish it was on here earlier!

Comment: @eschneider is correct. `System.Diagnostics.Tracing` is the portable API for tracing and is part of .NET Core. The most official source is the link to our official NuGet package. it's owned by Microsoft and fully supported. @daniel-plaisted's answer, while correct, is now superseded.

Comment: Nuget won't install this to my PCL `System.Diagnostics.Tracing 4.0.21-beta-23516 is not compatible with .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7.` how did you get it in?

Comment: Yeah, It doesn't appear to install on my system either.  Targeting a PCL with Windows 8.1 and .NET 4.5.1, I get the message: **Install-Package : Could not install package 'System.Diagnostics.TraceSource 4.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Windows,Version=v8.1', but the package 
does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.**

Comment: There's compatibility issues, they can be hard to diagnose, probably has something to do with what target framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the easiest way is to have a simple event in your PCL that will do nothing more than just publish appropriate eventargs (with message to be traced). Platform code can then subscribe to the event and do Trace.Write / Trace.WriteLine based on that event for you. Or you can pass a textwriter to do just logging.
A rough example:

```
public class PclTraceWriteEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    public PclTraceWriteEventArgs(string message)
    {
        WrittenMessage = message;
    }
    public string WrittenMessage { get; private set; }
}

public class PclTrace
{
    public TextWriter LogWriter { get; private set; }

    public PclTrace(TextWriter writer)
    {
        SetTracer(writer);
    }

    public PclTrace() { }

    public void SetTracer(TextWriter writer)
    {
        LogWriter = writer;
        if (LogWriter is StreamWriter)
            (LogWriter as StreamWriter).AutoFlush = true;
    }

    public async Task WriteAsync(string message)
    {
        if (LogWriter != null) await LogWriter.WriteAsync(message);
        OnMessageWritten(new PclTraceWriteEventArgs(message));
    }

    public async Task WriteLineAsync(string message)
    {
        if(LogWriter!=null) await LogWriter.WriteLineAsync(message);
        OnMessageWritten(new PclTraceWriteEventArgs(message));
    }

    public void Write(string message)
    {
        if (LogWriter != null) LogWriter.Write(message);
        OnMessageWritten(new PclTraceWriteEventArgs(message));
    }

    public void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        if (LogWriter != null) LogWriter.WriteLine(message);
        OnMessageWritten(new PclTraceWriteEventArgs(message));
    }

    public event Action<object, PclTraceWriteEventArgs> MessageWritten;

    protected virtual void OnMessageWritten(PclTraceWriteEventArgs args)
    {
        if (MessageWritten != null)
        {
            MessageWritten(this, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Classes in PCL can have a (static) variable in which you instantiate the PclTrace class, and platform code can react to that:

```
public static class SomeClassInPCL
{   
    public static PclTrace myTracer { get; private set; }
}
```

And finally, do this:

```
class MyAwesomeClass
{
    public MyAwesomeClass()
    {
        SomeClassInPCL.myTracer.MessageWritten += TraceMessageAction;
    }
    public void TraceMessageAction(object sender, PclTraceWriteEventArgs args)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(args.WrittenMessage);
    }
}
```