# Get the name of the executing Func<Task<T>> how in Portable class library?

Tags: c#

How do I get the name of the method I am executing given the following signature:

```
MyMethodAsync( ()=> myservice.GetCustomer)

public async Task MyMethodAsync(Func<Task> taskToExecute)
{
    //Get the name of the task that is executing 
    //   eg "myservice.GetCustomer

    taskToExecute.??
}


public async Task MyMethodAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskToExecute)
{
    //Get the name of the task that is executing eg 
    // "myservice.GetCustomer
```

}

Desired result: `myservice.GetCustomer`

I have tried as follows, but it does not work. Ideally I'd like to do it without reflection

```
string methodName = taskToExecute.GetMethodInfo().Name;
```

Comment: Keep in mind what lambdas do. Your code is roughly equivalent to `MyMethodAsync(CompilerGeneratedMethod); Task CompilerGeneratedMethod() { return myservice.GetCustomer; }`. Hoping to extract `myservice.GetCustomer` from that is going to be very difficult. Do you really need to stick with that exact signature?

Comment: I would like to log the method that is invoked ideally that is the main purpose. What is the best I can get?

Comment: Here you [go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2652481) bud

Comment: @Nobody  hi I forgot to mention the most important thing is a portable class library. I cannot seem to have Stacktrace

Comment: if that is so check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593496/equivalent-for-system-diagnostics-trace-in-pcl-library) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28015917/6611487).

Comment: Could you go Expression based? Don't know if that's available in PCL. With a little work you'd be able to get the method names but then you'd have to compile and invoke the lambda manually. You'd never be able to get the variable name (myservice) though - - just the method name. It also wouldn't work well (or at all?) if your lambdas were complex (multi statement).